# How to align items on an ItemsWrapGrid?

Tags: winui-3

How do you align left the items and add some padding around the content ? I tried `RelativePanel` too for size but content seems to remain in the center and padding has no effect, which I added to the `StackPanel` as the second alternative to enforce alignment.

As the result I wish to see a `Line` followed by a text altogether aligned left as an item on the `ItemsWrapGrid`, padding enforced and each item shall have equal width. Not like here :

[image]

[image]

```
 <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items}" Margin="5">
     <GridView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <ItemsWrapGrid  Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </GridView.ItemsPanel>
     <GridView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ChartLegendItem">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="3">
                 <Line x:Name="Stroke" Stroke="{x:Bind Color, Converter={StaticResource HexBrushConverter}}" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="10" Y2="0" StrokeThickness="5"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Caption}"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </GridView.ItemTemplate>
 </GridView>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about "align left the items"?

Comment: I tried your code with 9 items, and it renders 2 columns (5, 4) aligned to the left. Each item (legend) renders its colored line and its caption. It might be easier if you post a drawing maybe.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding - Thank you for the comment. `HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="3">` has no effect - in brief.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding - now I added the drawing you requested.

Comment: Do my `GridViewItem` and `GridView.ItemTemplate` solution and AndrewKeepCoding 's `CustomGrid` solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the `GridViewItem`s, and you can do it with the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```xml
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style
            BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultGridViewItemStyle}"
            TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

**UPDATE**:

To answer your question about item width, you could use a custom grid like this one:

**CustomGrid.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="App1.CustomGrid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" />

</UserControl>
```

**CustomGrid.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1;

public sealed partial class CustomGrid : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ItemsSource),
            typeof(object),
            typeof(CustomGrid),
            new PropertyMetadata(default, (d, e) => (d as CustomGrid)?.RefreshGrid()));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(MaxColumns),
            typeof(int),
            typeof(CustomGrid),
            new PropertyMetadata(1, (d, e) => (d as CustomGrid)?.AdjustColumns()));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ItemTemplate),
            typeof(DataTemplate),
            typeof(CustomGrid),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public CustomGrid()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public int MaxColumns
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(MaxColumnsProperty);
        set => SetValue(MaxColumnsProperty, value);
    }

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    private void RefreshGrid()
    {
        RootGrid.Children.Clear();

        AdjustColumns();
        AdjustRows();

        if (ItemsSource is not IEnumerable<object> itemsSource)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (object item in itemsSource)
        {
            int columnIndex = RootGrid.Children.Count() % MaxColumns;

            int rowIndex = RootGrid.Children.Count() / MaxColumns;

            ContentPresenter itemContentPresenter = new()
            {
                Content = item,
                ContentTemplate = ItemTemplate
            };

            Grid.SetColumn(itemContentPresenter, columnIndex);
            Grid.SetRow(itemContentPresenter, rowIndex);

            RootGrid.Children.Add(itemContentPresenter);
        }
    }

    private void AdjustColumns()
    {
        if (RootGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count == MaxColumns)
        {
            return;
        }

        RootGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxColumns; i++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition columnDefinition = new()
            {
                Width = GridLength.Auto
            };

            RootGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition);
        }
    }

    private void AdjustRows()
    {
        if (ItemsSource is not IEnumerable<object> itemsSource)
        {
            return;
        }

        int requiredRows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)itemsSource.Count() / MaxColumns);

        if (RootGrid.RowDefinitions.Count == requiredRows)
        {
            return;
        }

        RootGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < requiredRows; i++)
        {
            RowDefinition rowDefinition = new()
            {
                Height = GridLength.Auto
            };

            RootGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```xml
<local:CustomGrid
    Grid.Column="1"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}"
    MaxColumns="2">
    <local:CustomGrid.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ChartLegendItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Line
                    x:Name="Stroke"
                    Stroke="{x:Bind Color, Converter={StaticResource HexBrushConverter}}"
                    StrokeThickness="5"
                    X1="0"
                    X2="10"
                    Y1="0"
                    Y2="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Caption}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:CustomGrid.ItemTemplate>
</local:CustomGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks but as you can see P2 is pretty long caption, and its trailing not displayed. Can I set the `ItemContainer`'s widths to the longest caption and hence form a regular matrix shape ? (`MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"`)

Comment: Yes, one way is to bind the width of `ListViewItemPresenter` to the width of `GridViewItem` and specify the width of the first `GridViewItem`, [my
 test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hxHc.png "see it!!!"). Or define width in `GridView.ItemTemplate`, see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/bf8f076c9df47ebe08e68a96f4a4cb086af48da5/WinUIGallery/ControlPages/GridViewPage.xaml#L68 "!"). @Tommy

Comment: Did my updated answer help with your issue?